# Assigning ViewController to a delegate, Is it good?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am newbie in iOS programming, Recently I came across a tutorial where author assigned a ViewController to a textField delegate. Is it good to do this? As Xcode is giving me warning.

```
discussIDTextField.delegate = self;
```

`self` is DiscussViewController and above code is inside DiscussViewController.m

Code works fine but I don't like yellow bubbles showing on my screen while writing codes. If I want to get rid of this warning what should I do?

> Warning : Assigning id from incompatible type
>   'DiscussViewController'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The view controller (self) has to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. So your `@interface` definition should look something like this:

```
@interface DiscussViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

And then of course in the implementation implement some of the delegated protocol methods.

Answer (score 3):

In your .h file add UITextFieldDelegate between < > so that your view controller becomes text field delegate and then in the .m file implement delegate methods that you need.

```
@interface DiscussViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```